# EmberJS Express API | TypeError: app.route is not a function at module.exports

Tags: node.js, express, ember.js, mongoose, promise

I have been stumped by a server api for my ember project for a week now. I cannot get a modular api to work and it's driving me nuts.

Console related:
mongod, node server, heroku local(or ember s)

First, the error I'm trying to resolve: (shows when going to http://localhost:4500/notes)

```
TypeError: app.route is not a function
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\routes\noteRoute.js:21:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:109:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Accurate\Projects\emberjs\accurate2\AccurateEmber2\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
```

Here is my folder schema:
**api**
- -controllers
- - - - noteController.js
- -models
- - - - noteModel.js
- -node_modules
- -routes
- - - - noteRoute.js
- -package-lock.json
- -package.json
- -server.js
**app**
- - serializers
- - - - note.js
**config**
**dist**
**node_modules**
**public**
**server**
etc...

---

My server.js file:

```
// Allow POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

//DB Vars
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/Ember2';

// mongoose instance connection url connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var options = {
    useMongoClient: true
};
mongoose.connect(uri, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR connecting to: ' + uri + '. ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Succeeded connected to: ' + uri);
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var note = require('./routes/noteRoute'); //importing route
app.use('/notes', note);

//middleware catch
app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.status(404).send({ url: req.originalUrl + ' not found' })
});

app.listen(port);


console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

My noteRoute.js: (commented code are alternatives I have tried and still received the error. Essentially, I am unable to interact with my database.)

```
'use strict';
/*let router = require('express').Router();
let note = require('../controllers/noteController');

router.post('api/notes', note.create_a_note);
router.get('api/notes', function (req, res){
    note.list_all_notes});

module.exports = router;*/

module.exports = function (app) {
    let note = require('../controllers/noteController');
    let router = require('express').Router();

    router.post('api/notes', note.create_a_note);
    router.get('api/notes', function (req, res) {
        note.list_all_notes
    });

    // note Routes
    /*app.route('/notes')
        .get(note.list_all_note)
        .post(note.create_a_note);

    app.route('/notes/:noteId')
        .get(note.read_a_note)
        .put(note.update_a_note)
        .delete(note.delete_a_note);*/
};
```

My noteModel.js:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let NoteSchema = new Schema({
    title: { 
        type: String, 
        required: 'Kindly enter the name of the note' 
    },
    content: { 
        type: String 
    },
    author: { 
        type: String 
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Notes', NoteSchema);
```

My noteController.js:

```
'use strict';

let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Note = mongoose.model('Notes');

exports.list_all_notes = function(req, res){
    Note.find({}, function(err, note){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(note);
    });
};

exports.create_a_note = function(req, res){
    let new_note = new Note(req.body);
    new_note.save(function (err, note){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(note);
    });
};

exports.read_a_note = function(req, res){
    Note.findById(req.params.noteId, function(err, note){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(note);
    });
};

exports.delete_a_note = function(req, res){
    Note.remove({
        _id: req.params.noteId
    }, function(err, task){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Note successfully deleted.' });
    });
};
```

My note.js serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    /*primaryKey: '_id',
    serializeId: function (id) {
        return id.toString();
    }*/
    normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType){
        payload = {notes: payload};

        payload.notes.foreach((note) => {
            note.id = note._id;
            delete note._id;
        });

        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
    }
});
```

I have been using a combination of Postman and the browser to check on API status.
Having this modularized API is a must as the application will grow much larger. Having all of the get, post, put, delete, etc. in the server.js will be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

`noteRoutes.js` should be something like this:

```
let router = require('express').Router();
let note = require('../controllers/noteController');

router.post('/api/notes', note.create_a_note);
router.get('/api/notes', note.list_all_notes);

module.exports = router;
```

If you then include it in `server.js` using this (what you already have):

```
var note = require('./routes/noteRoute');
app.use('/notes', note);
```

this will give you URLs of `http://localhost:4500/notes/api/notes` for your `GET` and `POST` requests. If this isn't the URL you want then you'll need to adjust the route paths accordingly. e.g. If you just want `http://localhost:4500/notes` then change the path to `router.get('/', note.list_all_notes);` and the same for the `post()` call.

You'll then need to fix the problems with your controller. You've repeatedly used this pattern:

```
if (err)
    res.send(err);
res.json(note);
```

This won't work, in the error case it will try to call both `res.send` and `res.json`, which will fail because you can only send one response.

There may well be other problems but you'll need to debug them as and when you hit the relevant errors. The suggestions above should be enough to get you past your current error.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am getting some feedback via postman now. Just some alterations to the emberjs side to display the documents now.

I altered the `if (err)` to have an else statement as well.

Comment: Also, you some light on how API routing works. I _did_ want it to be at `/notes` instead of `http://localhost:4500/notes/api/notes`